# Getting an error with preventDefaults while creating an email api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, nodemailer

I am trying to create an emailing api for which i have a form.
But it showing an error saying

```
Uncaught TypeError: e.preventDefaults is not a function
```

What is the problem here and is the syntax with axios function right?

```
    const [name,setName] = useState("");
    const [email,setEmail] = useState("");
    const [message,setMessage] = useState("");
    const [sent,setSent] = useState(false);

    const formSubmit=(e)=> {
        e.preventDefaults();

        let data = {
            name:name,
            email:email,
            message:message
        }

        axios.post('/api/forma',data)
        .then(res => {
            setSent(true);
        },resetForm())
        .catch(() => {
            console.log("message not sent");
        })

    }

    const resetForm = () => {
        setName("");
        setEmail("");
        setMessage("");
    
        setTimeout(()=> {
            setSent(false);
        },3000)  
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Fix `e.preventDefaults();` to `e.preventDefault();`. You made a typo mistake.